# assigning a lead to customer field in Phonecall activity

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-2015

My code generates leads in Microsoft dynamics CRM system. There are phone call activities associated with leads. There are "To" and "From" properties in the phone call activities which can be either a contact or lead. I need my code to assign the lead to those properties. I implemented this:

```
Entity account = new Entity("lead");
lead_id= service.Create(account);
Entity activity1 = new Entity("phonecall");
activity1["description"] = "Phone call activity";
activity1["to"]=account;
activity1.Attributes.Add("regardingobjectid", new EntityReference("lead", lead_id));
service.Create(activity1);
```

### It doesn't show any error but doesn't work. I can see that the "to" field in the activity is empty in CRM system.

```
public static Guid createActivity(Guid lead_id, Entity sendr, Entity recvr)
{
Entity activity1 = new Entity("phonecall");
activity1["description"] = ImgURL;
var activityParty1 = new Entity("activityparty");
activityParty1["partyid"] = sendr.ToEntityReference();
activity1["from"] = new[] { activityParty1 };

var activityParty = new Entity("activityparty");
activityParty["partyid"] = recvr.ToEntityReference();
activity1["to"] = new[] { activityParty };
activity1.Attributes.Add("regardingobjectid", new EntityReference("lead", lead_id));
Guid acc_id = service.Create(activity1);
return acc_id;
}
```

Exception at:  Guid acc_id = service.Create(activity1);

Comment: I don't see anything that could go wrong with the code if lead_id is not default guid and sendr and recvr parameters are not null. Which line does it exactly fail? Can you update your question and add a comment on the exact line it fails?

Comment: Hi, I have updated the links to the screenshots that I have taken. lead_id is not null, still, the activity fails to create with the message that it's null. And when I remove those lines, it works just fine.

Comment: Did you check your sendr and recvr objects and their GUIDs? One of the must be an entity of the type "lead" with an empty  GUID.

Comment: Thanks. Recvr id is null. I will debug the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Activity Party is the connection between PhoneCall and related "to" field. Create an add an activity party.

Early Bound:

```
  activity1.To = new[]
  {
     new ActivityParty() {PartyId = account.ToEntityReference()}
  };
```

Late Bound:

```
 var activityParty = new Entity("activityparty");
 activityParty["partyid"] = account.ToEntityReference();
 activity1["to"] = new[] {activityParty};
```

Comment: ActivityParty - Missing reference.

Is there any dlls that I am missing?

Comment: Any reference to strongly typed objects in CRM would indicate proxy types are enabled. Just merely convert the answer to support late bound types. Although I would highly recommend using early bound types as it would have pointed to the type of object (activityparty) "to" is expecting. I have updated the answer to also cover late bound type scenario.

Comment: When I add those lines before service.Create(activity1), my code throws an exception stating Lead_id is 000-00-000... When I comment those lines, my code works just fine.

Comment: And when I add those lines after creating the activity, they obviously don't work.

activity1.Attributes.Add("regardingobjectid", new EntityReference("lead", myLeadId));
            service.Create(activity1);

Comment: What exactly seems to be the issue? Can you updateyour question and post the code where it seems to be failing?

Answer (score 0):

You should reference an EntityReference every time to want to associate entities. More, the entity you're associating with should already exist.
So you can rewrite your code as:

```
Entity account = new Entity("lead");
lead_id= service.Create(account);
Entity activity1 = new Entity("phonecall");
activity1["description"] = "Phone call activity";
activity1["to"]=**account.ToEntityReference()**;
activity1["regardingobjectid"] = **account.ToEntityReference()**;
service.Create(activity1);
```